# "Git Bash here" is not preserving bash history between sessions

Tags: bash, shell, windows-7, git-bash, msysgit

I am running Git-1.8.0-preview20121022 on Windows 7 and the install was with "Git Bash Only" (least intrusive to Windows cmd).

When I open the Git Bash from the start menu shortcut, everything is fine with the history.

But when the `Git Bash here` context menu (either the `git-cheetah` shell extension one or the simpler registry one) is what launched a session, the commands from that session are not saved to the `.bash_history`.

How could figure out why this is happening? Or better yet, does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by adding this line to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `HISTCONTROL` and `HISTIGNORE` as well.

Comment: didn't work for me. I needed to have a HISTFILE set.

Comment: This worked for me on Win 7 64-bit. Was tearing hair out for a while as wouldn't work - then realised I'd created with Windows line-endings, which breaks. If having issues, double-check you've saved with Unix line-endings using an editor that supports this - not e.g. Notepad!

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60718848/6680510

> Create the following files
>
> ```
> ~/.bash_profile
> ~/.bashrc
> ```
>
> And put the following line in both of them
>
> `PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'`
>
> To do this from the console (git bash) itself use the following
> commands
>
> ```
> echo "PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'" >> ~/.bash_profile
> echo "PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'" >> ~/.bashrc
> ```
>
> **What `history -a` means**
>
> From `history --help` command
>
> > -a append history lines from this session to the history file
>
> **What is `PROMPT_COMMAND` ?**
>
> > Bash provides an environment variable called PROMPT_COMMAND. The contents of this variable are executed as a regular Bash command just
> > before Bash displays a prompt.
>
> **Difference between `.bash_profile` AND `.bashrc`**
>
> `.bash_profile` is executed for login shells, while `.bashrc` is
> executed for interactive non-login shells.
>
> When you login (type username and password) via console, either
> sitting at the machine, or remotely via ssh: .bash_profile is executed
> to configure your shell before the initial command prompt.
>
> But, if you’ve already logged into your machine and open a new
> terminal window (xterm) then .bashrc is executed before the window
> command prompt. .bashrc is also run when you start a new bash instance
> by typing /bin/bash in a terminal.
>
> On OS X, Terminal by default runs a login shell every time, so this is
> a little different to most other systems, but you can configure that
> in the preferences.
>
> References
>
> https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html
> https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc

Answer (score 5):

Putting

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a ~/.bash_history'
```

into the .bash_profile did it for me.