# How to use (Windows Powershell) GitShell commands history after restart?

Tags: windows, powershell, git-bash

I'm using Gitshell (Powershell) for windows (7) downloaded from official Github website. How to use commands history  after restart?

- command `exit` instead of `x` is ineffective (as sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941155/5826730))
- can't see any `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_history` file (to make it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14199536/5826730))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't have a persistent history. You can (sort of) [save/restore](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156792.aspx) the command history yourself with something like this:

```
Get-History | Export-Clixml 'C:\path\to\history.xml'
Import-Clixml 'C:\path\to\history.xml' | Add-History
```

Use [`Get-History`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849691.aspx) to list the history and [`Invoke-History`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849737.aspx) to invoke a command from the history. The save and restore can be automated by putting something like this into your PowerShell [profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx):

```
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -Action {
  Get-History | Export-Clixml "$env:USERPROFILE\ps_history.xml"
} | Out-Null

if (Test-Path -LiteralPath "$env:USERPROFILE\ps_history.xml") {
  Import-Clixml "$env:USERPROFILE\ps_history.xml" | Add-History
}
```

However, that will not make "historical" commands available via the cursor keys. If you want that you need to run PowerShell in something like [Console2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), or [Clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/).

Comment: You can also use `#history_id_number` tab completion feature.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I accepted the answer but actually command history **cursor keys** is what i was looking for and as You wrote its unavailable. Its unavailable with Console2 also. I give up with other consoles you suggested.