# Windows terminal CTRL + R vs Git Bash CTRL + R | Commands are not saved after reopening

Tags: git-bash, windows-terminal

I have been using windows-terminal (powershell) and when I am using it I can easily do `CTRL + R` in the command line. Whenever I do `CTRL + R`, and start typing, it brings up my old commands that I have typed, even if I open a new terminal or shut the computer the search still works.

I have recently switched to git bash and while CTRL+R works in bash, it does not save the results. Which means if I close the Git Bash terminal and open up a new one I no longer can find anything with `CTRL+R`

Is there an easy way to save the results like it happens in powershell?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/10488498/15399131